# Can Livewire Laravel have a parent controller/component to avoid code repetition in dynamic steps?

Tags: laravel, oop, model-view-controller, backend, laravel-livewire

I am creating a dynamic logic for my order process. I have 5 steps to follow in my order, I have created an endpoint **process-order/{{$id}}** and inside this end point I have created 5 components each component belongs to a different step.

[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LratZ.png)

Since all 5 steps use the same order data, user data, address data etc. I was thinking is it possible so I create a parent class which fetches all data I need so I can just extend from this parent class and don't do DRY code.

I tried to do some researches on internet but not so much info I provided, there were articles explaining nested components which I don't think has so much to do with my specific problem.

Comment: Please paste text into block quotes instead of hyperlinking images of text rendered. When prompted to do something like `enter image description here`, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

If your backend code is not so much, you can utilize Laravel's [anonymous components](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#anonymous-index-components) to keep view code of all the steps. You can pass all the required data as props. It gives you the flexibility to have all the code in one class and have views split into different files